# Ordering array items while adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an empty array.

```
var empArr = [];
```

I'm creating multiple base64 url strings and add them in to the above array. So far all good. My question is while adding these url strings in to the array how can I order them the way I need?

I used `splice()`. But since some url string are generated more quicker, this method doesn't seem to work.

```
empArr.splice(i, 0, "Lychee"); // i = the position
```

Is these a way to create a temp array with the i value and then splice when all base 64 strings are completed? Or any other way of doing this more effectively?

Comment: A binary search tree would be a better choice than an array for this.

Comment: can you share the JS function you have created?

Comment: @m69 Thanks. That's a very good suggestion :) Would you mind showing how?

Comment: @Bekki I added a simple example of a b-tree, which I think will work fine in your case.

Comment: @Bekki Did you end up using a b-tree, or did you stick with arrays?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understand you want to add extra padding in to array variable right.

You can add at last or begging of the array variable like

```
//It will add at last
empArr.splice((empArr.length-1), 0, "Lychee");

//It will add at first
empArr.splice(0, 0, "Lychee");
```

Hope it helpful for you...

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a very basic b-tree; it can do two things: insert new data, and extract the data in order. This should be all you need in your case.

```js
function Tree() {     // CONSTRUCTOR
    var root = null;

    this.insert = function(item) {
        var newLeaf = new Leaf(item);   // CREATE NEW LEAF WITH DATA
        var branch, leaf = this.root;
        var before;

        while (leaf != null) {    // FIND PLACE IN TREE
            branch = leaf;
            before = newLeaf.comesBefore(leaf);
            if (before) leaf = branch.left
            else leaf = branch.right;
        }
        if (this.root == null) this.root = newLeaf // FIRST LEAF IN EMPTY TREE
        else if (before) branch.left = new Leaf(item) // ATTACH LEAF TO BRANCH
        else branch.right = new Leaf(item);
    }

    this.shift = function() {
        var branch = this.root, leaf = this.root;

        if (leaf == null) return null;   // EMPTY TREE
        while (leaf.left != null) {   // SEARCH LEFTMOST LEAF
            branch = leaf;
            leaf = branch.left;
        }
        if (leaf == this.root) this.root = leaf.right // ROOT IS LEFTMOST
        else branch.left = leaf.right;   // BRANCH INHERITS RIGHT SIDE
        return leaf.item;
    }

    function Leaf(item) {    // CONSTRUCTOR
        this.item = item;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;

        this.comesBefore = function(other) {  // REPLACE BY REAL DATA COMPARISON
            return (this.item < other.item);
        }
    }
}

var t = new Tree();

t.insert("lychee");
t.insert("pomegranate");
t.insert("tangerine");
t.insert("banana");
t.insert("starfruit");
t.insert("grapefruit");
t.insert("apple");

while (result = t.shift()) console.log(result);
```